12 V high side P-channel MOSFET driving with 3.3 V logic help
I am making a triple half bridge with discrete components and need some real help figuring how to do it. I am doing this because I love a challenge and would like to learn more about FET driving and selection. Here are my constraints:

12 V three phase BLDC, inductance across phases is 4700 µH (U+W/U+V/V+W).
3.3 V MCU (the pin is 5 V tolerant however if that opens up any interesting hacks).
Phases driven by PWM at 24 kHz.

I've had a crack at a design using an NPN to pull the gate low, but I am sure there are better ways to do this. R1 is a pull up, R3 is a pull down, and R2 controls the current input. Q1 turning on shorts the FET gate low. D1 is a flyback of course, needed due to the inductive load.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Is there a simpler design than mine to control a P-FET?
I really have no idea how to find suitable FET and NPN components for this task. I understand voltage and current limits (how not to release magic smoke), I however have no idea about switching speeds, saturation currents, and gate charges etc. What are key equations and graphs to get this right?
Any component recommendations would be amazing if you could.


Hi,
At what speed do you need to turn the P-channel ON and OFF? 24kHz just noticed.
Consider using  push-pull to drive the P-channel.

With just a pull-up (R1), 24 kHz will be very challenging.

@winny why is that?

Depending on the size. of R1 either a lot of current will be used or the circuit will be slow at turning OFF

Calculate the time constant of R1 * M1cg (gate capacitance). Compare with your 24 kHz.
